# Editing Appearance of Lookup Field in SP Workflow Email

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, claims-based-auth

I have a workflow that sends an email when a new item is added to a list. The email includes the creator of the new item, which uses a lookup value.

```
CurrentItem-CreatedBy-String = [%Current Item:Created By%]
```

which when emailed, comes out with the following format

```
i:0#.w|Domain1\ddono25
```

I understand that the beginning "i:0#.w|" is because of the claims authentication, but is there any way to strip that portion out when an email is sent?

Answer (score 0):

You should have the option to select the Display Name or User Name(among other options)

[image]

Comment: Yes, those are the exact options. In this case, we wanted to be able to see the username along with the domain. Like for the example above, using "As String" comes out as "i:0#.w|Domain1\ddono25", email comes out as "Ddono25@Domain1.com", DisplayName does not have the <domain>\<username> that we would like in the email, etc.

Comment: As long as you don't use a federated location or external claims provider, the claims prefix will be 7 characters long. As a workaround, you could use the utility actions "Extract from a string..." from that account and output into a string to use... http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/How-Claims-encoding-works-in-SharePoint-2010.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Create a variable and use utility then you will get in your format

Answer (score 0):

Try using the action:

**Extract Substring from Index of String**

1. In the string variable of the action, set [%Current Item:Created By%]
2. in the numerical value(after starting at), set 8
3. In Variable(Output to), set it to any variable(example DomainName).
4. Use the DomainName variable(under Workflow Variables and Parameters) in your email body.